# How to read errors from database when using TableAdapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tableadapter

I am using TableAdapter, but I cannot capture any errors that comes from SQL. Here is a piece of my code:

```
        errorText = "";
        DataTable AddFilesResult = new DataTable();
        var dockDataAdapter = new Dock.DAL.DockDatasetTableAdapters.Dock_Files_AddTableAdapter();

        try
        {
            AddFilesResult = dockDataAdapter.GetData(
                location,
                name,
                relation
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorText = ex.Message;
        }
```

I tried checking 'dockDataAdapter.Connection', but I don't see any error info in there as well.

I created my adapter using this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx

I would appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - it was in my code :/. Error can be captured as it should - with try/catch statments.